# How to localize label using algorithm and algorithmic packages

Tags: captions, languages, algorithms, naming

I am writing a paper in Italian and I need to include pseudo code in my latex document so I am currently using the `algorithm` and `algorithmic` packages. At the top of every algorithm the label `Algorithm 1` is shown, but I'd like for it to be in Italian instead. I have previously included:

```
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

with no change whatsoever, is there any way to localize it?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\title{ASD}
\author{haunted85}
\date{Ottobre 2012}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{}
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Questo è un algoritmo.}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\STATE int Count(int $N$)
\STATE $sum = 0$
\FOR{$i \leq N$}
\FOR{$j = i \leq N$}
\STATE $sum = sum + 1$
\ENDFOR
\ENDFOR
\RETURN $sum$
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). It is always preferable to post complete [minimal working examples](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) rather than code snippets because this helps people to answer you.

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino thank you, editing the question right now!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Either use `\floatname{algorithm}{Algoritmo}` (see section 4.4 of the `algorithms` manual) or,  if you want to be able to switch between Italian and English caption names, redefine `\ALG@name` using `babel` macros.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english,italian]{babel}

\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{algorithm}

% Alternative A
% \floatname{algorithm}{Algoritmo}

% Alternative B
\makeatletter
\addto\captionsitalian{\renewcommand{\ALG@name}{Algoritmo}}
\addto\captionsenglish{\renewcommand{\ALG@name}{Algorithm}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\caption{An algorithm}
\begin{algorithmic}
\STATE Some text.
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I've deleted my answer since yours provides better solutions `:)`