# change "Algorithm 1:" to "Algorithmus:" in algorithm package

Tags: algorithms, naming

I am using the algorithm package and I need my algorithm to be labeled as "Algorithmus: XYZ" instead of "Algorithm 1: XYZ" where XYZ is my caption for the algorithm.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to localize label using algorithm and algorithmic packages](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/76110/how-to-localize-label-using-algorithm-and-algorithmic-packages)

Comment: thank you! Now it displays "Algorithmus 1: XYZ". Now I only need the number to be removed, if it is possible.

Comment: Sorry for missing the part about numbering.

Answer (score 6):

I think loading the package `caption` is the appropriate way.

```
\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{alglabel}{\bfseries\csname ALG@name\endcsname:}
\captionsetup[algorithm]{labelformat=alglabel}
```

---

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\makeatletter
\addto\captionsenglish{\renewcommand{\ALG@name}{Algorithmus}}
\makeatother
\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{alglabel}{\bfseries\csname ALG@name\endcsname:}
\captionsetup[algorithm]{labelformat=alglabel}
\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\caption{An algorithm}
\begin{algorithmic}
\STATE Some text.
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```